# Running function inside document.write which document.write inside window.open

Tags: javascript, function, alert, window.open, document.write

```
function capture(){
  var screenshot = window.open("", "_blank", "menubar=2,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,width=" + 680 + ",height=" + 550);
  screenshot.document.write("<center/><img id='jpeg' src='"+img+"'><br/>");
  screenshot.document.write("<a download='vfr_capture.jpeg' href='"+img+"'>Download</a>");
  screenshot.document.write("<button id='myLink' onclick='popOut()'>Test</button>");
}
function popOut(){
  alert("Clicked");
}
```

Button myLink is appear after window.open, if i click it none happen. How can i make alert("Clicked") appear? Is it onclick function is disable inside document.write?

PS: I've tried to put function popOut() above the function capture(), but it still doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `popOut` in the `onclick` in the popup window is not the `popOut` in the *current* window. The two window environments are separate.

You can make it available to the other window, though, by adding this to the end of `capture`:

```
screenshot.popOut = popOut;
```

[**Live Example:**](https://jsbin.com/sajofa) *(since Stack Snippets don't allow `window.open`)*

```
document.querySelector('input').onclick = capture;
function capture(){
  var screenshot = window.open("", "_blank", "menubar=2,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,width=" + 680 + ",height=" + 550);
  /* Commented out since I don't have your `img` variable
  screenshot.document.write("<center/><img id='jpeg' src='"+img+"'><br/>");
  screenshot.document.write("<a download='vfr_capture.jpeg' href='"+img+"'>Download</a>");
  */
  screenshot.document.write("<button id='myLink' onclick='popOut()'>Test</button>");
  screenshot.popOut = popOut;
}
function popOut(){
  alert("Clicked");
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me">
```

Comment: Thanks Sir Crowder for the help! So with your answer i realize it's possible to put onclick on DW, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Both the functions are in different scopes

```
function capture() {
    var screenshot = window.open("", "_blank", "menubar=2,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,width=" + 680 + ",height=" + 550);
    screenshot.document.write("<center/><img id='jpeg' src='" + img + "'><br/>");
    screenshot.document.write("<a download='vfr_capture.jpeg' href='" + img + "'>Download</a>");
    screenshot.document.write("<button id='myLink'>Test</button>");

    screenshot.document.getElementById('myLink').onclick = popOut
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p86pn64a/)